# (homework) tag should be deprecated (Voting's over! You won't believe what won!)

Tags: discussion, tagging, homework

> **Note.** After over one month of discussion, and more than one week of voting, I think the community has decided.
>
> 1. [Leave the tag alone:](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16335/8348) 43 upvotes (20.38%)
> 2. [Consider the tag deprecated, but do not remove it from the system:](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16336/8348) 12 upvotes (5.69%)
> 3. [Request that the tag be burninated and blacklisted:](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16337/8348) 156 upvotes (73.93%)
>
> So it seems like we'll be requesting that [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) is burninated and blacklisted. See [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16425/8348) for the next (and final) steps in the process.

---

1. New users don't normally include it, whether or not their question is homework. On the list of [newest questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), most are of the homework type, but few are tagged as such. If the goal is to identify or filter homework question, the tag fails at that.
2. Despite of 1, it is used often enough to be the top tag on the site. So it gets to be the one inserted in the page title. For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/182598/147263) is titled *homework - Finding the adjoint of an operator* instead of *functional analysis - Finding the adjoint of an operator*. The beginning of page title heavily influences the way Google treats the page (this is why the tag is put there to begin with). The (homework) tag deprives the page titles of the site from including the most important key words.
3. Gold tag badge confers the ability to unilaterally close duplicates with that tag (and SE might extend this ability to other closure reasons in the future). This makes sense if the badge indicates the expertise in some subject. But homework is not a subject. There is no such thing as being an expert in homework.
4. The tag is featured on the front page for new users, promoting the image of the site as a homework factory:

   [image]

If it's too much work to delete the tag,  I suggest to at least change the tag wiki to say that the tag is deprecated and should not be used. The users who wish to receive a hint instead of full solution can say so themselves. Tags are for classification, not communication.

Comment: Another small problem with meta tags like homework is that you can end up with only the meta tag on a question, and not a single tag that indicates what the question is actually about.

Comment: "It it's too much work to delete the tag". Can't the higher ups delete it and blacklist it with a few clicks?

Comment: @GitGud SE has the ability to remove tags entirely, and this would be a case where they would use it. There would still be quite a bit of work required to clean up any questions that would end up without any tags, but those are badly tagged right now as well.

Comment: While in principle you raise some good arguments, I have an issue with the third reason: (1) unilateral closures can be reversed by users; (2) at the moment this is only for duplicate, and if someone can close as a duplicate more questions because of the homework tag, it's a positive thing; (3) What happens when someone gets a gold badge in [tag:soft-question] or [tag:big-list]? Do we blacklist those as well, just because "you can't be an expert on big lists"? Again, the other three points are good and provoke some thinking, but the third one is not very good.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The community hammer on soft questions and big lists makes it practically impossible to get a gold badge there.

Comment: @Michael: True, even more for big lists; but on soft questions it seems that me and Qiaochu steadily approach a silver badge + 1k rep. So with time it seems plausible that at least one of us might have a gold badge too.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If that ever happens, use your powers wisely...

Comment: @Michael: Well, since I already have these powers in at least six tags, I suppose I will. In either case, I'm not [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R-XqGaf9xiQ/Tuwd8ykRzLI/AAAAAAAAHtE/AHVYGQ01cwk/s400/chalice.jpg) [Nazi](http://images.wikia.com/indianajones/images/5/52/Donovan_death.jpg) [guy](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-kt7NF0TzP_Q/UW9A47416xI/AAAAAAAACfI/EB4BxHDSV-M/s1600/tumblr_m3bpydbjvc1qlar22o1_1280.jpg). :-) (I'd compare myself to Indie, who has chosen wisely, but all things considered he's a pretty horrible human being. So I won't. But he's still cool, though.)

Comment: Personally, I'll prefer to keep the homework tag and question that are really homework without this tag should simply be closed and removed from the question pool.

Comment: You've completely persuaded me. I think StackExchange can tell people that the 'homework' tag should be used under extreme circumstances. If this cannot be done, then they should not feature it for new users. Great argument!

Comment: Well, this would result in many people losing their bronze/silver/gold badge for homework questions. That's probably going to be a heartbreaking experience.

Comment: "Tags are for classification, not communication." I agree that the [homework] tag doesn't serve a purpose in terms of classification. Proof: no one searches MSE for questions tagged [homework].

Comment: With 46 upvotes vs. 1 downvote, the meta community clearly supports this proposal. How can we move it forward?

Comment: Interestingly, in [another question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/621/do-we-really-want-a-homework-tag) a proposal to remove homework tag received total score -5.

Comment: @Martin: At the time it was a freckle, now it's a mole.

Comment: Here is a [related point](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1661/12952) on an old answer

Comment: @Alexander: Joel makes a point about asking homework questions. Not about the tags used to identify or not these questions.

Comment: May I add the following?:  5. Homework questions will, at some point, no longer be homework questions.  6. It's already deprecated on StackOverflow for similar reasons ([ref.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100)).

Comment: homework = not reusable. Not reusable must be depricated rather than (or together with) the tag.

Comment: While we are on topic, get rid of the "self-learning" tag too.

Comment: If we ban homework, we won't need a homework tag.

Comment: While we are at it, let's simply delete all questions that have a HOMEWORK tag. That will certainly help de-clutter the place. Most homework questions could be more than adequately answered by reference to a wiki page anyway.

Comment: @wolfies: While we're at it, let's delete all the questions from the site. Surely they can all be answered by adequate research and studying. It will also free the time of many users to pursue more productive things.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Better to keep this on topic (i.e. _homework_, which by its name is intended to be done at home - not by other people on the internet). As it is, many (if not most) homework questions are just specific variants of a more general question that has already been answered on SE: and instead of referring people to the more general answer, the infinity of specific instances gets asked and answered here ... which is plainly neither in the interest of the student nor the site. I suggest: use the homework tag as an efficient way of cleaning up the site.

Comment: @wolfies: And no amount of false positive that will disappear with this "big cleanse" is worth keeping? Please let me know, so I can start tagging everything you ever posted on the site as [homework].

Comment: @This is much healthier. So what happens now? Clearly the community agrees with you. How does this go from this post to the actual deletion of the tag?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Please read my last comment. Thanks.

Comment: @GitGud The mods are talking it over- let me get back to you.

Comment: "Homework" tag should be changed to "Partially done Homework Problems"

Comment: @ArthurFischer I think it is a bad idea to vote on this *here* (in my opinion you should start a new thread for the vote for better visibility) and further and more crucially I think it is a potentially a  bad idea to vote in this way without further explication. In particular I think to say one should vote for "the option" one agrees with is designed to cause confusion and debate after the vote. For example, if somebody is for 3 chances are they prefer 2 over 1. Should/will/may they vote for 2 too? I think it ought to be clear how the votes will be interpreted beforehand.

Comment: I would propose to vote like this: First vote on deletion only Yes/No (and impose say a two-thirds  majority or more of "yes" for this to happen). If "no" wins, then vote deprecation yes/no (with simple majority).

Comment: @ArthurFischer  I suggest changing the title of the question to something like "Poll: should ...?" Otherwise the users of main site will not know  that something changed here. It appears to them in the sidebar in the same way as it did for about a month.

Comment: @quid: I hemmed and hawed for a few days over whether I should create a separate thread. There are benefits to posting a separate thread, but also potential problems. For one, it would create a near duplicate of this current thread (which would likely also be [meta-tag:featured]) which may cause confusion about the connection between the two. In the end I also felt that having the overall discussion in the same place would be more beneficial than problematic. _[cont...]_

Comment: _[...inued]_ As for the issue of the system itself: as I am sure you are well aware, there is no voting system that is completely unproblematic. I feel your proposed system contains much more systemic bias. Why should the deletion (or, any other) option be tested first? Why must this first option achieve such a stricter standard in order to "win"? For example, if there are 55% "yes" votes in the first vote, and 51% in the second, can we really claim that there is a clear winner?  (In the end, if there is a clear _loser_ but no clear _winner_ in the current method we can have a run-off vote.)

Comment: @Arthur: Maybe add a "Pat Buchanan" option? (the ballot is confusing!)

Comment: @ArthurFischer possibly the changing of the title, which is a good idea, was good enough for visibility. One can certainly debate about the details of the voting procedure. My main point is really that the run-off you potentially propose likely will not make much sense. To deprecate is presumably the top choice for only very few so chances are it could be the clear looser. But, it could be a compromise/fall-back option. Somehow this reflects orig. proposal/motion: delete or if not at least deprecate. (For the 2/3 maj: del is the only irreversible) But perhaps let us see how things go now.

Comment: To avoid any misconception: I voted for deletion. It is not that I have some personal interest to make a win for deletion more complicated.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Just curious: are you currently handling $\approx 80\%$ of all moderation tasks on the site? Everywhere I see moderator's action, it's you. You should demand a pay raise.

Comment: @This: For the last week or so, pretty much. It _is_ abnormal. It appears that more than half of the mods are currently busy with other matters (conferences, vacations, etc.). I've put in a request for a 20% increase, and the SE team said they'll oblige. Now I just have to ask the fine folks of math.SE what 20% of 0 is.... :-/

Comment: @Arthur: Maybe put [featured] back?

Comment: @AymanHourieh A lot of upvotes does not necessarily mean that every voter agrees with removing the tag. I upvoted this question because it is a good discussion point, but I have not yet decided what my opinion is.

Comment: So is there a time frame for the vote? It's been about nine days (so pretty much anyone interested in this issue has been able to vote, I think), and I don't think anyone can argue with the result right now.

Comment: Not sure why you've added to the title "You won't believe what won!". It is completely logical and sensible that most think the homework tag should be destroyed.

Comment: @mathh: I interpret it as clickbait parody. http://www.clickhole.com/search?q=%22you+won%27t+believe%22

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is possible to be an expert on soft questions.

Answer (score 144):

## The (homework) tag should be burninated and blacklisted.

---

This means that we will request the SE team to completely remove the tag from the system and ensure that it cannot be re-created. This will result in a large number (at present [over 900](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/201122/posts-tagged-with-only-one-selected-tag?tag=homework)) of [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions, which will be the responsibility of the community to fix.

Upvote this answer if you agree with the above option. (Downvotes will be ignored, so please ***do not downvote***.)

Comment: Can we also have a vote to ban taxes? That might be quite popular amongst the masses, though not necessarily entirely helpful

Comment: [Current number of upvotes on this answer](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/16337?site=meta.math&filter=!GeEyUcJFJVsF5), for those under 1000 rep.

Comment: +1, but I'm a bit concerned about the procedure here: this is (now) displayed prominently as the top answer, and there's no indication that there's another two options.  Additionally, the reader is told not to downvote (and is criticized if they do), so if they don't know about the other options, they might think that not upvoting is what they should do.  (Also, by what margin would this answer need to win by to be implemented?)

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: Unfortunately, this is probably the best we can do with the tools readily available. If you look at the "banner" added to the question above, you'll see that the three options are named, with a link provided to the relevant answer. I don't have a percentage needed to win in mind, but currently almost 80% of the votes have gone to one option. I imagine this would satisfy any reasonable requirement.

Comment: Oh, I simply didn't see the message up top.  It's fair enough then.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: while I have no uses for the link to see number of upvotes you posted, I still can't figure out how to actually use it. What exactly need to be done to use that code?

Comment: @Gina One the number of upvotes counts in such a poll. When some users downvote, disregarding the directions, the score of an answer does not accurately reflect the number of upvotes on it. Only users with at least $1000$ reputation can see the number of upvotes by clicking the score. So I posted a link that makes it possible for everyone to see the number of upvotes if they wish. When clicked, it currently shows `"up_vote_count":106`. The rest of the code is some unavoidable fluff.

Comment: The moderation work of Arthur Fischer was finally rewarded ...  with a gold badge, the second-ever [Great Answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/great-answer) badge issued on meta.

Answer (score 36):

## The (homework) tag should be left as is.

---

Upvote this answer if you agree with the above option. (Downvotes will be ignored, so please ***do not downvote***.)

Comment: Some men simply want to watch the homework tag burn.

Comment: @ArthurFischer what do you think is the probability the two down votes comes from the same person who voted for the first option.

Comment: @Lost1 I would consider the probability as rather low, since the down-votes did not happen at about the same time.

Comment: [Current number of upvotes on this answer](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/16335?site=meta.math&filter=!GeEyUcJFJVsF5), for those under 1000 rep.

Comment: The homework tag should be left as it is. Many students have tough homework and they need help with their homework. Maybe their chapter is too hard and they need help with homework. Homework tag should be left intact.

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: This is not about getting rid of homework questions on math.SE, but only of removing the tag [tag:homework]. [so] went through something similar many moons ago, and (quality) homework questions [are still welcome there](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255499).

Comment: @ArthurFischer So, why not leave homework tag as it is?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent: Some of the reasons are highlighted in the question above. (You have to scroll down because some stupid moderator keeps on adding stuff to the top.) In short, the tag provides no information about what the question is about, it is not uniformly used on homework questions, and it ends up giving the site the image of a homework factory (whether that is true or not, I guess it's not good PR).

Answer (score 32):

I am posting this in order to give users an opportunity to vote for an opposite proposal. (Since it is a pretty radical change, I think we should also weigh the arguments against the removal of the tag.)

I am making this post CW - feel free to add arguments why you consider this tag useful.

---

Why the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag could be useful:

- It helps users who do not want see trivial stuff, since most frequently questions tagged (homework) are rather simple and such users can ignore this tag.
- It helps users who do want to help students by giving hints and nudging them into right direction - since these are precisely the questions where hints are more expected than full-fleshed answers. (Some users certainly consider this site not only as site for asking questions and giving answers, but also the site for teaching and they try to use pedagogical approach to needs of students asking questions.)
- It serves as a kind of an indicator which says: "Wait! This is a homework question! If you answer it, could you, please, try to give a hint instead of full answer?"
- Some kind of general "policies" or "etiquette" for dealing with homework questions has been formed on this site in lengthy discussions. (Although not all users agreed with them and not everyone followed them.) Would removing the homework tag mean also abandoning the agreements about dealing with homework questions? Or should after the removal of the tag the same policies be applied to all posts which "smell like homework"? (Which is somewhat subjective criterion.)
- It indicates that OP is still learning math, and it encourages answers which not only answer the question, but also provide additional insight, references, hints, etc.

Certainly the tag does not work perfectly. Not all homework questions are tagged as such. Here we must rely on the honesty of the poster. The best thing we can do is to explain newbies, that if the question comes from a homework, then they are supposed to add (homework) tag.

Also many people post full solutions to homework questions. But even if the (homework) tag reduces the number of full answers only by some percentage, it is a good thing. (So it helps this site not to become homework-factory.)

---

> 1. New users don't normally include it, whether or not their question is homework. On the list of [newest questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), most are of the homework type, but few are tagged as such. If the goal is to identify or filter homework question, the tag fails at that.

Then more experienced users are supposed to explain newbies about the tag. I do not think we can do much more than that with this issue.

> (4) The tag is featured on the front page for new users, promoting the image of the site as a homework factory:

I think that this tag is used precisely for the opposite purpose - so that the homework questions can be identified and they are dealt with in a different manner. So, in fact, it should (at least in theory) help against problem with this site being "homework factory".

---

I did not address 2 and 3, since I don't know how to solve 2 and I do not consider 3 to be much of a problem. (At least it is not a bigger problem for this tag as for gold badge in any other tag.)

Again, I've posted the answer as CW, so anyone feel free to address these points.

Comment: We usually do not know which questions are homework and which questions come from mock exams, textbooks, or other sources. Asking people all the time whether something is homework is pointless and sounds accusatory. And without it, we are not going to educate users to use the tag. Users themselves can always write that they only want hints- and even that is often ignored. I think the problem is bad questions without any background or motivation, not homework in itself.

Comment: I assume we'd be adopting a policy of "if this is homework, please say so" to replace "if this is homework, please use the tag". That makes the last two bullet points obsolete.

Comment: To make explicit that a user only wants hints, we could introduce a (hints-only) tag.  Not that people will actually honor such a request... :-)  (Or does such a tag already exist?  I couldn't find it.)

Comment: @MarnixKlooster Such tag has been discussed on meta. In fact, some people has suggested using (homework) tag for this purpose. See, for example [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8608/proper-use-of-the-homework-tag-redux/8621#8621). And also the following: [Suggestion for “Hint-Only” Tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/), 
[Request for a tag for homework hints/evolution rather than solution](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/) and
[How Should I ask Questions that I just need Hints on?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11258/).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Suppose we were to remove the homework tag and as such expected to users to ask for hint only answers if they desired them. Would hints then be discouraged if the question doesn't explicitly ask for hints? Would anything less than a full solution be deemed acceptable?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I think hints are sometimes perfectly good answers. What people here deem worthy of being upvoted, accepted, downvoted, or closed will no doubt still vary widely.

Comment: It would be a good thing to edit these answers frequently: Some users (like me) may change their mind after having read the other answers. Since reading them usually takes more than 5 minutes, one ends up with a locked vote.

Comment: @barto How many times do you get to change your vote in real-life polls, such as elections?

Comment: @900sit-upsaday It goes like $\sin\left(\frac{\pi t+\sqrt5}{2t}\right)$, $t$ time.

Comment: @barto http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4311/why-restrict-my-ability-to-change-my-vote-once-i-have-editing-priveleges The topic of this post is the closest I was able to find to discussing *editing a pots just for possibility to change a vote*. Anyway, if you think it is necessary, you can edit the answer and then change your vote. But I have the feeling that such behavior is generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 25):

This is not an answer for or against the proposal. This is merely some comments about the technical aspects of the proposal:

1. I *think* that we can in fact ask SE to nuke the entire tag and blacklist it, if that is what people want. (There are already a few tags that are explicitly blacklisted; examples include the old "algebra" tag (now split into [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra) and [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), and the implicit tags "math" and "mathematics".) The whole deal about editing the tag-wiki to indicate that a tag is deprecated happened with the "algebra" tag because we needed a transition period to carefully retag all the questions thus-tagged. As far as I can tell from this proposal this is not necessary (except for the odd question that only has the "homework" tag and nothing else).
2. This is more of a note-to-self (or other mods): if we go through with this proposal we will have to also edit [this FAQ item](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) appropriately. (Alternatively we can also just deprecate it, which will involve also editing the main FAQ post and the Help Center item which contains a link.) Note that much of the functionality of that FAQ item is currently duplicated and generalised in [this newer FAQ item](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).
3. (Suggested by Martin Sleziak) If the tag is removed, also some [comment templates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) should be updated. And also the faq post [on meta-tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Comment: Yes, we can ask the SE folks to [burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info) and blacklist the (homework) tag.

Comment: Some SEDE queries which can give list of posts tagged only ([tag:homework]) are given in this post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/questions-tagged-only-as-homework

Comment: @Arthur: Hooray for Trogdor references.

Comment: As a "factual speculation" regarding the level of user support, anything that proposes MSE change its practices to be the same as those of Stackoverflow gets an automatic 10-15 upvotes from people who don't regularly use MSE but are sometimes/always reading the meta.  The number may be higher these days due to the Network Hot Questions visitors from Stackoverflow who see something eye-catching like "remove homework tag!" on the Comuunity Bulletin.  It looks popular anyway from current vote counts, especially the zero downvotes, just not as much as the total would suggest.

Comment: @zyx Could you tell us me you can identify who votes how on a question? That knowledge would come in quite handy for us site mods from time to time.

Comment: No such ability was necessary to draw the conclusions, which you don't particularly seem to dispute (so far).  Take a look at the meta.MSE vote counts of obvious suspects, for example.  Apart from the question being a non sequitur, vote trolling sarcasm is rather unbecoming, as you must know.  @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: @zyx I think you vastly overestimate the amount of users that read metas for sites they don't actively participate. I'm the exception and not the rule. There can be some distortion of votes in these cases, but that happens mostly when a controversial meta post is linked in high-traffic places, and that hasn't happened in this case as far as I know.

Comment: @MadScientist, it used to happen for really high profile stuff only (other than a few exceptional users as you mention who vote on everything), but now there is the Network Questions driving SO traffic to the math.SE community bulletins.

Comment: @zyx I cannot dispute the conclusion, becuae I don't have access to voting data in that detail. That does not mean I believe it. I do understand that you detect sarcasm in my comment, but I don't get the "vote trolling" part.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, in practice (whether intended or not, and usually it is part of the intent) the point and the result of such comments is not communication with the recipient, but a vote-trolling theatrical *aside* to the meta readers.  Knowing that this will, very probably and predictably, generate a few, or more than a few, one-directional votes (there is no -1) on the ridicule and sarcasm directed at particular individuals or their statements.

Comment: @zyx It is true that my comment was not mainly directed at you. It was mainly directed at people lacking the knowledge to appreciate that what you wrote is at best an informed guess. To compensate, I upvoted your last comment.

Comment: The comment in question described itself as "factual speculation".  Whether that is read by others as being a guess about facts, based on facts, or (what is actually the case) both at once, the idea that it was a guess of some kind seems to have already been conveyed.  It is not "at best" an informed guess, it "is" an informed guess, and I don't think that Mad Scientist or the SE affiliates or the other visitors from afar would dispute the premise that they tend to support proposals harmonizing MSE's practices with the rest of network and especially the larger sites. @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: If the tag is removed, also some [comment templates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) should be updated. And also the faq post [on meta-tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Comment: It took SO several months to manually review the ~20k homework questions it had to sort out the good ones from the bad.  With nearly 30k of them here and a much smaller userbase a mostly manual process would be infeasible.  That said, on SO almost all the negatively voted questions were deleted and almost all of the positively voted ones were kept.  There're ~24000 positive voted homework questions here, ~4000 0 score ones, and only ~900 negative score questions; so filtering on score to decide what to delete might not work.  SO was much harsher on homework questions long before the tag ban.

Comment: @DanNeely Thanks for sharing the experience. Yes, Math has been historically soft on HW dumps. I am not suggesting mass-review of questions tagged [homework], for two reasons: (1) the usage of the tag poorly correlates with the nature of the question; many (if not most) homework questions aren't tagged as such. HW questions not tagged as such may actually be worse on average than those that are tagged. (2) With very few exceptions, [homework] is accompanied by  subject area tags -- the site's editors have been taking care of that. So I think the tag can be simply burminated.

Comment: Could we please (temporarily?) remove the answers that are not the options to be voted for? This is placing some of the options at the very bottom of the page, which might influence the voting.

Comment: @JasonPolak The answers do contain arguments related to the issue, as does the question... Note that the poll-answers are linked to directly from the question: one can click through directly to the answer one supports.

Answer (score 19):

The main application of the homework tag is to reduce the use of the empty word "homework" in question titles, and to allow users the option to signal homework in a machine-readable way instead of loading up the question with junk phrases like "I didn't understand this question from my algebra homework".  That entire phrase can be nuked and replaced by two tags, Algebra and Homework.  Now if you would like to promote a zero-tolerance policy that encourages edits to remove, on sight, any text in the question that can be replaced by a tag, that would be a great thing for MSE and any other Stackexchange site I can think of.  But this works better the more tags are available.

On the other hand, if deprecating the tag reduces the amount of absurd site politics related to homework, then: *go for it!*

Comments on the numbered points:

(1) is not a problem.  The purpose of the tag is not to ID every question that happens to come from homework, but to permit that to any user who wants to do it (and in that case, yes, doing it by tag is better).  This happens in a significant fraction of the homework questions, and every time that it does, the people who want to use that tag for filters and searches experience a gain in efficiency.

(2) is Stackexchange's problem to solve, if it is a problem at all. There are simple and obvious solutions like banning certain tags (whether specified by the users, the moderators, or SE itself) from the page title.  This issue affects other tags than homework, and SE will sooner or later have to tune its algorithm for the page title.

(3) Same as for (2), except that this problem applies to *all* tags, and if it is a problem, is a structural one for Stackexchange to address. Gold star in one tag closing things in the intersection with other tags where they have only silver, lead, clay or tin-foil expertise, presents similar issues whether the gold is in homework or not.

(4) the "factory" aspects of the site are not, in my opinion, influenced by the tag display, and exist no matter what tags will be used and **no matter whether the questions have anything to do with homework**.  There are people here who receive eager answers to their questions that appear to derive from industry work, for which they are paid.  Some of the eager answerers are the same folks who rail against homework on meta, and some of those provide the freebies even when question is *advertised* as being for a job!  There is a very unequal distribution of knowledge and consequently a small set of Givers who answer a large set of Takers.  This is inevitable in the Q&A model and not much a function of what the first few tags are.

Comment: Regarding (2), SE already solved this problem by eliminating meta tags on most sites. The SE position is that if the most-used tag that gets put in the title is a useless tag, there is some fundamental issue with the site's tagging scheme that should be fixed, and not worked around.

Comment: That the meta tags get a lot of use is evidence that they are useful.  Maybe removal of meta tags and not the existence of the tags is the "fundamental issue with the site's tagging scheme" that needs to be addressed.  The anti metatag position was a personal imposition by SE's former leader.  While some parts of the argument against those tags made sense, the overall absolutist position did not.  Now that the founder is not in command maybe the matter can be revisited.

Comment: While Jeff was one of the loudest, and probably the least diplomatic proponent of removing all the meta tags, he was by far not alone. I've criticized the tag system heavily in the past, I think it is borderline broken on sites like Arqade, but I still don't think meta tags are worth the trouble. They are simply not that useful.

Comment: Is the tu quoque in your final point really necessary?  It doesn't seem to add anything to your position.

Comment: *tu quoque* is quite a different concept (it's a response to accusations, for example). The behavioral observations in the final paragraph illustrate the incoherence of the "factory" rhetoric, which is used on the meta as a propagandistic way of discrediting particular positions. The OP is not the one who pushes that rhetoric (and is not one of the "folks who rail against homework on meta"), but he did take it up in this post. Therefore, in addition to the response to point (4) in itself, there is some relevance to highlighting other aspects of the situation. @ScottH.

Comment: I felt that the use of the term was expedient, sorry to have misused it.  The OP's final point seems to be about impressions of the site, while your response to it seems to be about mechanics of the site.  I guess I just don't understand either the OP's final point, your response to it, or perhaps both.

Comment: The response to OP-4 can be summarized in two points. First, any Q&A site that provides useful answers at no cost will be a factory, across the whole spectrum of questions that it serves, whether it wishes to be one or not.  Second, as both an observation of the past and a prediction of the future, that the "factory" rhetoric (which is irrelevant given the first point) will only be used in relation to homework.  In fact the "factory" aspects, such as the ability to get an answer to pressing real-world questions, will be celebrated where there is no suspicion of homework. @Scott

Comment: @Mad Scientist The problem lies not with use of meta tags but, rather, with SE's lack of support for meta tags. Meta tags can be very useful for filtering content. All of the problems mentioned here would disappear if SE properly supported them. One of the primary problems with the site now is that it has grown too large for users to filter out the questions that they like. The solution is not to throw out the baby with the bath water but, rather, to improve the filtering capabilities. That is what we should be demanding from SE, not some kludgey patch to an inadequate platform.

Comment: "That the meta tags get a lot of use is evidence that they are useful." Strange argument. I bet if one could tag "mathematics" the tag would be used a lot.

Answer (score 7):

## The (homework) tag should be considered deprecated, but not removed from the system.

---

"Deprecation" of a tag in this manner is not something officially supported by the SE framework, and it will still be possible for users to use the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag. It will therefore be the responsibility of the community to remove it from new questions, and inform users that the tag should no longer be applied.

Upvote this answer if you agree with the above option. (Downvotes will be ignored, so please ***do not downvote***.)

Comment: [Current number of upvotes on this answer](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/16336?site=meta.math&filter=!GeEyUcJFJVsF5),  for those under 1000 rep.

Answer (score -19):

Even if the OP does not use "homework" tag, the users ("community police") can still attach this if they're reasonably sure that this is homework. On one recent post, though, the OP specifically said "this is not homework" because most questions are! So, maybe we should have a "not a homework" tag??

Comment: The tag wiki clearly states it shouldn't be added by other users without specific statement by the OP, and I think the *vast* majority of users respect this fact.

Comment: I will be sure to go back and add the tag "Not analysis" to all of my questions.

Comment: @RghtHndSd and while you're at it, remember the buddys "not-set-theory", "not-topology" and "not-algebra".

Comment: @AlexR: But everything is set theory! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay, then we must make use of "not-much-set-theory" and "some-set-theory"!

Comment: At least 18 people have no sense of irony.