# Fate of the (homework) tag: The community voted.... now what?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-management, tag-blacklist

Well, the results of [the voting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/14981/8348) seem pretty conclusive:

> - **Leave [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) alone:** 43 upvotes (20.38%)
> - **Deprecate but don't delete [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework):** 12 upvotes (5.69%)
> - **Burninate and blacklist [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework):** 156 upvotes (73.93%)

So we'll be requesting that the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag be <s>hanged, drawn and quartered</s> burninated and blacklisted. But before we can make this a reality, is there anything we as a community must, or should, do first?

Comment: Revolution is coming.

Comment: Wake up, Mister MSE. Wake up, and smell the ashes.

Comment: Given that the flood of homework questions never stops, and many people answer in full before a more responsible tutorial/hint discussion can get going, I'm not sure what the tag change will accomplish.

Comment: Or, is this a sweeping victory for those who want us to do their homework? "I don't even need to tell you where I got this problem"

Comment: Will, I guess the idea is that nothing about the attitude towards HW has changed. Only the tag is gone. May be the askers now need to learn something to tag properly? (not holding my breath)

Comment: @WillJagy Bad homework questions tend to be self-identifying even without the tag, and hopefully this will lead to people actually using relevant tags. I don't expect any other changes to happen regarding the reception (or robo-answering) of low-quality questions.

Comment: Usually people who post homework just throw in the question, and not any effort AT ALL. I don't think it's a "victory" for them. Most probably we will know when it is homework anyway.

Comment: @WillJagy Tag removal *might* decrease the number of incoming hw questions. If the existing ones get better treated by Google, now that their page titles will begin with some keywords instead of "homework". *Google->find a similar question on SE->get help from the existing answer* is how SE is supposed to work.

Comment: How about 1) Ask SE to remove homework tag from all posts unless it is the only tag. 2) Blacklist homework tag so that no new user can use that tag 3) put all the remaining posts that only contain the homework tag on hold.

Comment: @achillehui 1) and 2) will be done, per the post below. As for 3), batch-closing is not something that SE ever did (as far as I know). Some of those are actually quite good questions, and have nothing to do with homework. Some posters even say this explicitly: "I could not find a tag that fits, so I put homework since it's the first one listed".

Comment: I don't know if it has been suggested but what if we had another stack exchange?  Math Homework Stack Exchange.  It would make get reputation here a tougher accomplishment but it would also clean up a lot ... a lot.  Even if you had the slightest hint that a question here felt like homework, you could delete and migrate it to MHSE.  Plus there would be no homework in MHSE (for the obvious reason), so why not?!

Comment: We can disagree about how the issue is handled once its relocated to MHSE, as Will J. points out deleting the tag seems to give students carte blanche; if they go to MHSE at least everyone (the student, those answering... possibly a prof.) knows they were getting help on their homework.  The only "problem" (not really a real one) is that occasionally questions might get migrated there when they should be here.   If MHSE was created then on MetaMHSE we could have discussions like, "Should we just have a few good questions of type xyz and close the rest? Or not?" And such debates wont exist here

Comment: @Squirtle See [Would splitting the site into more elementary and more advanced questions help?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9239/)... the general opinion there was that the answer is "no".

Comment: Yeah but the best answer is kinda unsatisfying: Playing devil's advocate,"Shouldn't it be split into elementary school math, high school math, undergraduate and graduate math?"  I'm with @Hurkyl on this, "where to draw the line, wouldn't volume be the guide?"  It makes sense.  MO doesn't have volumes and volumes of questions, SE does; SE wouldn't if it were at the level of grad students and advanced undergrads.  I think the real issue here is that people are annoyed by the inflow of questions...  I think this sort of proposal should be reconsidered. Then only MHSE would have massive vols of Qs

Comment: @Squirtle There are other issues, such as: why would SE want  to host MHSE? They brand themselves as a [network of **expert** communities](http://stackexchange.com/) which generate reusable content. A homework help site does not quite fit.

Comment: A slightly tangential question: When the homework tag is removed from Math SE, what happens to users who hold the tag badges for the (homework) tag?

Comment: @glace: They will no longer have those badges. Tag badges are determined by your tag scores which themselves are computed once per day. As you cannot have a tag score in a nonexistent tag, you cannot have a tag badge for a nonexistent tag. In fact, tag badges are the _only_ badges that can be easily revoked. For the other badges there generally needs to be evidence of "heinous cheating". (See the [MSE badge faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/214632), or [this MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/214632) for more.)

Comment: I'm a Physics/Mathematics student, and MSE has very often helped me on homework. (I try hard on my questions before asking, and try to write high-quality questions). If "homework" is being blacklisted, I... just won't tag my question as homework. =\

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Right.  We're only talking about removing the homework tag, not banning homework questions (which would be impossible).  See the [previous discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/14981/12952) for more details.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Oh. Well, no problem there.

Comment: @900 Good idea. I should have thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: @user26857 Please do not start your comment with something like "The right question is the following" if you direct a comment to a specific user. I thought that first part of your comment was a bit patronizing. It's better to directly state your own question alone.

Comment: Arthur, did the tag commit treason against the crown for it to be hanged, drawn and quartered? And did they later export it to "A Peasant's Quest" to try and fight Trogdor?

Comment: The tag removal will make no difference. How about 'smells-like-homework'?

Comment: @legâteauaufromage For your tranquilidad (sorry, but I don't know the enghish word for this - if there is one) I've removed my comment. (And sorry for not keeping the pace with the speed you change your usernames.)

Comment: @copper.hat: Will there be a Weird Al parody cover "Smells Like Mathematics"? If not, then it's not worth it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Maybe Günther could do a slightly risqué version?

Comment: "Now what?" Now I stop visiting math.SE, since I can no longer filter out homework problems.

Comment: @BenCrowell The tag never helped with that very much, as is witnessed by homework-induced irritation expressed on meta for years. If ignoring one tag solved the problem, there would not be blood-shedding debates over it. .... May I interest you in a [filtering bookmarklet](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#interesting) that hides HW more efficiently than any tag ever did?

Comment: There is a lot of outdated information in the [comment template thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates) now. I'm not comfortable to go haywire with the relevant answers there, this is just to notify someone more experienced that this remains to be done.

Comment: I'm late to this discussion, but I would've thought the homework tag would be useful for filtering out homework problems.

Comment: Are...you...serious? You guys voted to remove the homework tag? My, my how things have changed...

Comment: @littleO: Not really; that is point 1. in the list of reasons to get rid of it in the question linked at the beginning of the post we're commenting on.

Comment: Wait... seriously? You guys are banning the most popular tag? Why would you ban a tag that has the most followers, that just sounds mathematically incorrect.

Comment: It should be immediately removed

Answer (score 31):

Its days are numbered, starting today. You've voted, and while a little controversial, we'll support your decision. What remains is just the 'final arrangements', so to say.

#### We'll need some preemptive cleanup

Things with the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag applied to them *do* tend to have some issues. Take a stroll [to the end of the very long tail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework?page=585&sort=votes&pagesize=50) - use your flags and close votes judiciously. Moderators can very likely make quite liberal use of the delete button on the back third.

Remember, a lot of the cruft *isn't* likely to surface again regularly, so a healthy dusting of brooms is in order. Fix what can be fixed, close / delete that which can't. As you proceed, *remove the tag*. When you see new uses of it, remove it, leave a comment pointing at this post:

> Hello, and welcome to Math SE! [We're in the process of removing the homework tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/the-community-voted-now-what/), so I've removed it from your question. It looks fine otherwise, good luck! **or** (advice on  how to improve the question)

`Hello, and welcome to Math SE! [We're in the process of removing the homework tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/the-community-voted-now-what/), so I've removed it from your question. It looks fine otherwise, good luck! **or** (advice on  how to improve the question)`

#### We'll blacklist prior to completely removing the tag

We need to turn the tide back, or the flow will just make the effort perpetual. At the same time, we don't want to more thoroughly confuse new users that find it. In a day or two, we'll prevent the tag from being applied with an error message pointing at this meta post. This will also force the tag to be removed before edits can be saved. Hopefully, this keeps it *out* while minimizing confusion.

#### One week from today, it's history

I'm setting a reminder to come back on 8/6 and remove all instances of the tag. This will be done all silent-like, so make sure you've got at *least* the worst of the worst cleaned up before it falls into eternal obscurity.

#### Why not just burn it now?

This approach gets rid of the tag entirely, very quickly, without a lot of cost or aggravation. Someone that used the tag earlier today isn't going to hit a lot of confusion while trying to edit something, at the same time we make sure that it stops coming in. The real 'work' here is in cleaning up the worst of the worst, which isn't very difficult to do.

We'll be monitoring it, and in pretty close touch with your moderators. As soon as they signal us to say "we're as ready as we're ever going to be ..", the tag is history, so it might be sooner than a week.

Thanks to all in advance that help clean up the mess, and we're happy to support you as you do.

Comment: I have added the version of comment template you have suggested, which can be copied directly from the post. I hope it is ok. Another suggestion: Maybe it is sufficient to put this information into edit summary (it will still be visible to the OP and anyone who views revision summary).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good idea on making it easy to copy. I think it's sufficient to just comment - as the tag itself is going to be history soon, so any mention of it is at best ephemeral. There's no reason to keep mentions of it around in revisions, since it's soon moot.

Comment: What happens if a question with the homework tag is missed? Will the tag simply be removed from that question? What happens if the homework tag is the only tag on that question?

Comment: @robjohn When tags are [burminated on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260530/) (where this is done regularly), some questions become *untagged*. Hence the remark "Please care for the widows and orphans" there. Hopefully, the current cleanup effort will avoid creating too many of those.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: I just noticed that you have a typo in "burninated". May the wrath of Trogdor the Burninator be upon you!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Argh, too bad the comments aren't edible. Well, at least the question titles on main site are. Such gems there every time I run my smoke-detector script.  [Can someone explain this is plain english?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885994/).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: If comments were edible, I wouldn't need lunch. Stop trying to sell me your scripts. I'm a fan of chaos and entropy. Order is bad and unnatural.

Comment: Could we have another review task temporarily dedicated to going through questions with the homework tag? That way it can be organised and counted?

Comment: @Alizter Not feasible to change the software just for a one-time task. Those review queues are more complicated than they may look. To find questions with only homework tag, you can use the link at the top of [my answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16426/).

Comment: @TimPost Your reminder seems to have forgotten to remind you. How are things going to proceed?

Comment: There are around 150 questions left tagged with only homework.

Comment: The tag still exists ten days after it was supposed to have been deleted...

Comment: For that matter, it seems the tag was never even blacklisted; new questions are still being tagged with "homework".

Comment: Alright, my fault :) It was still set to _warn_, I moved it to block, and removed the tag completely. This resulted in only [ten 'untagged' posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged) which need some attention. Other than that, it's done.

Answer (score 16):

I don't have much to say about what is going to happen. But I do want to point out something about what is going on. This point was sorta brought up by another user, but the answer was deleted.

There are people currently removing the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag manually from questions. But I have seen some users removing it from "famous" questions which are old, and certainly had several tags and reasonable formatting.

> ## Please don't bump old questions which are properly formatted and have more than just a homework tag.

In fact, maybe we can collectively agree that in the next week or two, we should avoid bumping old questions *except* for the purpose of retagging/close-delete of questions which have only the [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag.

Comment: I would phrase this differently: if your sole editing action is to remove *(homework)* tag, then **don't do that**; the tag will be removed automatically and without bumping. Edit to **improve**.

Comment: Also, close-delete does not bump, and is often preferable to editing. Can I borrow your 30 daily votes to delete for a few days?

Comment: Borrow? No. Loan with interest? Sure. The interest rate is 6,000 USD per week, over 30 delete votes. This means that if you want to borrow a three days worth of votes, and we work out that you pay me back in a week, you will have to return me 90 delete votes and 18,000 USD. (Nothing personal, I just really want to attend many conferences, and I have no reasonable travel grants as a Ph.D. student.) The price is final and non-negotiable. Of course, if your university (or a university in your city) has a strong set theory group, we can exchange that with an invitation+travel expenses. :-)

Comment: Charging 6000 USD per week on 30 delete votes, this probably violate your local law of maximum interest rate. The contract may not be enforceable and the borrower may keep the delete votes until the legal issue get settled. This proposal may also attract tax collectors to look at your books. IMHO, this is not a good loan proposal but this is probably too late...

Comment: @achille: I am unaware of such laws, but they probably exist. But did I mention that each delete vote is worth nearly 100,000,000 USD on its own? So what's the interest rate now?

Answer (score 13):

Exactly how many active users do we have? I would suggest that 156 is a *tiny* fraction.

I've been an active user of the site for a couple of years and *had no idea* that this discussion was taking place. I find it questionable that a discussion with a different web address (meta) can impact on the ordinary site.

It seems a little like me getting a few of my friends around my house in the UK, 12 of us vote to nuke Russia and so the US has to nuke Russia.

**Don't get me wrong:** I do agree that the homework tag should be removed, but having such little support on a different site doesn't seem to give the motion any legitimacy whatsoever.

Comment: It was in the *Featured* column on the main site since June 16.

Comment: There's a lot of active users on the main site who have little or no interest in the goings on here on meta, which is unfortunate because meta is where discussions about the site occur. We cannot force these users to become active or even interested here. (For comparison, there were 437 ballots cast in the last moderator election. Should I turn in my diamond?)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday That obviously didn't work. You got about 220 votes out of how many users?!

Comment: How many active users the main site has is an interesting question with no obvious answer; it merits a separate question. The fact, already pointed out by Arthur Fischer, is that few of them take any part in discussions on meta. They may enjoy the fact that tag system is sensible, but apparently don't want to deal with boring [tag maintenance tasks](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12485/) and so forth. That's okay. But those who don't vote have to live with the decisions made by those who do.

Comment: @ArthurFischer You'll find that there are a lot of active users on the main site that have little or no idea that meta exists, nor what impact it has. This motion has 211 votes. There are 2019 *editors* (not just users) on the main site. Something needs to be done about getting more users involved. This site simply does not have a popular mandate.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday The site says there are 100,000+ registered users, but most of these are one-visit-wonders. There are 2019 *editors* on the main site. These are those with the editing privileged, and all have reputations 1,000+. That means about 7.7% of experienced users support this motion. (I am one of those!) My point is not against the motion but is a point about popular mandate and democracy.

Comment: "Something needs to be done" -- please propose your idea toward that. (Hm, where? I guess here on meta. Oops.) To emphasize the parallel with mod elections: Alexander Gruber was elected a moderator with the support of **86** users, and nobody's been questioning his mandate as far as I know. We can sit here and calculate percentages all day. But what exactly is to be done?

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Perhaps put some drop-down banner headlines on the main site, just like Wikipedia do when they're trying to get donations. A better thing would be to incorporate the meta site onto the main site - again, like Wikipedia do. We could have a "Policies" header along side "Questions" et al. There are lots of things that can be done. Every modern democracy in the World is trying to increase voter turnout and engagement.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday June 16 was somehow strategical chosen (right?), as one knows that most users are in a vacation now.

Comment: @user26857 The [proposal](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/14981/) was posted by me, on June 10. It had positive reception and was made featured a few days later. You can see the [timeline](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/14981/timeline?asc=True) of events. There was no particular reason for the post to appear when it did.

Comment: In fact 156 (or 211) is not a tiny fraction! If you check carefully can easily see that the number of active users on M.SE is rather low. (Of course, there are more than 211, but I don't think their number is more than 21100.)

Comment: FYI, this year ~23k (not very accurate) users had a nonzero reputation change.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: users do not need to be active to have a non-zero reputation change. Questions and answers get voted on even when the authors are inactive.

Comment: @robjohn I know, hence why I said it wasn't very accurate. It still gives a rough idea.  But I'm not sure why your pinging me about something I said in August.

Answer (score 9):

#### Update

Fewer than 50 homework-tag-only questions remain, and all of them are closed. Most of this post is obsolete, kept mostly as a demonstration of [ugly line gap](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16552/147263).

---

Some suggestions.

1. [Done] <s>Edit the tag wiki to say something like: "Do not use this tag; it will be removed soon. Instead, use a tag that describes the subject of your question, for example [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus), [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry),..."</s>
2. [Done] At present there are a [few hundreds](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/209647/posts-tagged-with-only-one-selected-tag-plus-the-score-and-number-of-answers?Tag=homework) of questions tagged only [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework); the number has been going down in recent days due to some activity on that front. They need to be edited; most  also need some improvements in formatting  and titles, not just another  tag.  The list is sortable by the score (click the Score column) in case someone wants to work on the higher or lower end of the spectrum. For some of the closed questions on the list, deletion may be a better choice than editing (up to the 10K voters, of course).  Also, a few of the closed ones have been merged into another question and can't be edited.
3. [FAQ post has been edited] I think the meta thread [How to ask a homework question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/) has been superseded by [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/); at least I always suggest reading the latter rather than the former, and so do some other users. The former one can be delisted from faq.

Comment: Necessity of doing something with the FAQ post was also mentioned in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/homework-tag-should-be-deprecated-votings-over-you-wont-believe-what-won/14988#14988) by Willie Wong (in the voting thread).

Comment: I've edited the [wiki and excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) to include a notice about its burnination.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SEDE. Is there any way to fork the query so it doesn't show deleted questions (or to use updated, rather than cached data)? It still shows 797 results, even though there are dozens of new deletions.

Comment: @T.Bongers Unfortunately, not. SEDE is updated once per week, on weekends. It is a read-only snapshot of SE database at that time. The last update was July 27, next one will be August 3. I'll see if I can come up with some approximation to the query using the search operators.

Comment: @T.Bongers I found a way to get the up-to-date list of homework-tag-only questions; see the update at the top of the post.

Comment: Currently there are less than 50 questions tagged with [tag:homework] only, and [they're all closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[homework]%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3a0). Is it time to nuke that tag for good? (Ps. I edited the answer to [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/) to remove the suggestion to use the tag; I think the rest of the advice there is still quite valid.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for editing that. I know robjohn already asked Tim Post about the delay. Maybe Tim is on vacation.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Could you share this amazing method to find an up-to-date list?  (I'd like to see these 50...  But if you don't want to share, I understand--some techniques are best kept hidden.)

Comment: @anorton To find questions with one particular tag, search `[tag name] is:question` and sort results by relevance. The system considers the questions with no other tag as  the most relevant.

Comment: Warm thanks. I think your generated list helped/speeded up the clean up immensely.

Comment: There's still like... 30 questions with only [homework] and they don't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: @AsafKaragila 30? Isn't that, like, the number of delete votes you have?

Comment: Yes, but then I won't be a billionaire anymore. Right now I am worth 3 billion dollars, with 30 votes remaining. Without them... Not as much.

Comment: Well, "all closed" [is history](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896005/inverse-of-lu-decomposition).

Comment: @DanielFischer This not the first "undead" appearance of the tag; now they are attached to questions where the poster has *very* low awareness of what they are doing.

Comment: Didn't expect it to be the first. But I forgot that you're probably out of close-votes for today already. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @DanielFischer I did vote to close eventually, after wasting a bit of time reformatting the question.