# Using [tag:] markup in posts creates an ugly gap between lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, design, markdown

Using `[tag:]` markup in posts on (meta.)math.SE creates an ugly and unnecessary gap between the current and the following line of text.  For example, see the following screenshot from [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what/16426#16426):

> [image: Screenshot]

Or this live example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. [here-is-a-tag-link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/here-is-a-tag-link) Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

The gap is even more prominent in lists:

> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. [here-is-a-tag-link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/here-is-a-tag-link) Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

On many other SE sites, such tag links are rendered with explicit boxes around them, and in such cases, increasing the line height may be unavoidable.  However, on math.SE, the tags are just written in a sans-serif font and surrounded by parentheses, so the extra line height is completely unnecessary.

Adding the following CSS rule to the math.SE style sheet fixes this bug:

```
.post-text .post-tag, .wmd-preview .post-tag {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

(Of course, instead of just slapping on a CSS patch like above, it would be better to fix the existing CSS rule which it overrides.)

Comment: Yes, it works fine in lists too. If you're feeling adventurous and want to test it, you can install the [devel version](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/devel/SOUP.user.js) of [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: Soup is good food. (You've made a good meal.)

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Thanks! Ugh, though... looks like that's really two bugs in one: first, that the default link colors here don't properly distinguish visited links from unvisited, and second, that the question / answer links on the search results page lack the class names that would normally override those colors e.g. on the front page. I can fix either or both in SOUP fairly easily, but I'll need to see what, if any, side effects messing with the default link colors would have. Also, if you feel like writing a proper bug report to replace the deleted one, that'd save me some work.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday: Huh, I didn't realize owner-deleted posts could be undeleted by the community. Anyway, I just cast the third vote, so it's undeleted now.

Comment: If the issue resurfaces, ping or make a new post.