# The warning for the blacklisted tag (homework) should be updated

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-blacklist

At the moment, when you try to enter [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag into a question you receive a message containing the text:

> The 'homework' tag is not allowed.
>
> Please do not use the 'homework' tag, it's currently deprecated and will be removed entirely within the week. For more information, please see [the related meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what).

[image]

This was added there during the [last cleanup](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what) before the removal of the blacklisted tag.

In my opinion, the sentence that *it will be removed entirely within the week* should be omitted. It made sense at the time when it was added, but now it is completely unnecessary.

[image]

Comment: This was [also mentioned](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/should-we-request-customized-messages-for-some-blacklisted-tags#comment61782_16750) in a comment to a related question about possibility of customizing warnings for blacklisted tags.

Comment: I almost think we could simply ask that the second paragraph be removed. On SO the message simply says "The 'homework' tag is not allowed." when you try to use it. Not much else really needs to be said, IMHO.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I think that a very probable explanation why there is only such short message on SO is that the possibility to make customized messages was not available at the time, it seems to be [relatively recent feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists). But I agree that there are blacklisted tags where an explanation would probably be more useful than here. (This is the reason why I bumped the other thread. We will see whether we get some input from other users on that.)

Comment: Just a minor comment: I think words like "deprecated" should be avoided in messages like these. I had to go to my thesaurus (who am I kidding, I googled of course) to see what it means. I'm not a native English speaker, but I think there are users with less knowledge of the language on this site than I have.

Comment: @DanielR: I agree. However, I want to point out that the percentage of people with a computer science background who understand that word is a bit higher than of the general populace ("deprecated" is used a lot in API documentations). So given the origin story of StackExchange, your comment has a chance of being the first time someone complained about it.

Comment: @WillieWong Is this the time I should be man enough to admit that I do have a computer science background...? :)

Comment: Let me see how easily I can get this fixed up.

Answer (score 4):

I derped.

This was supposed to be changed after we outright blacklisted (it originally warned folks, then ultimately blocked). The updated text is:

> Please do not use the 'homework' tag, it's not necessary. For more information, please see [the related meta discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/the-community-voted-now-what).

I planned to update it when I changed the behavior from warn to outright block, but somehow managed to overlook it. Sorry about that, it's set now.

Comment: I'm not certain if I like the phrase "it's not necessary". This could be interpreted as "_All_ questions here are homework, so why would you bother telling us?!" I can't think of an alternative right now, however. (Also, perhaps the link should go to [Thursday's meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/14981/8348) where the issue was discussed, rather the aftermath post.)

Comment: I agree with @ArthurFischer in that the meta link to discussion of what to do after vote is not that helpful. But I think my post is not the one to link to, either. We have a [FAQ item](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/) on homework questions: link there instead. The text could be: "The `homework` tag is not allowed. For more information on asking homework questions, [see the FAQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/)".